# SQL transpose rows to columns and adding new variable

Tags: sql, rows, transpose

How do I query this data using SQL:

[image]

to return this format, with `NA` for `NULL`

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx): `-- I use MSSQL`

```
SELECT DeptID,
       [1] AS transaction_1,
       [2] AS transaction_2,
       [3] AS transaction_3
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, transaction,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
   FROM Your_Table) A
   PIVOT
   (
      MAX(transaction) FOR rownum IN ([1],[2],[3])
   )piv;
```

Comment: rownum IN (transaction_1, transaction_2, transaction_3) will throw an error.

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal: What's error?

Comment: Oh, tks!, but after I check, I think [1],[2],[3]

Comment: Tks, I edited my code

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using MSSql Server,

Example with sql query,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionTable](
    [User_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionAmount] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (1, 22)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (1, 42)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (1, 18)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (2, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (2, 16)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (3, 82)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (3, 48)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([User_ID], [TransactionAmount]) VALUES (3, 31)
```

To get your result,

```
SELECT [USER_ID]
      ,Transaction_1     = [1]
      ,Transaction_2     = [2]
      ,Transaction_3     = COALESCE([3] ,'NA')
FROM   (
           SELECT [user_id]
                 ,[TransactionAmount]
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                      PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY(
                          SELECT NULL
                      )
                  ) AS rownum
           FROM   TransactionTable
       ) TransactionTable
       PIVOT(MIN([TransactionAmount]) FOR rownum IN ([1] ,[2] ,[3]))piv;
```

With renamed the column. It will definitely helpful to you.

**Note:** *TransactionAmount column must be nvarchar.*